# How to install Realtek RTL8723BE wifi PCIe Wireless Network Adapter

Tags: wireless, software-installation, realtek

My system is Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit and kernel is 3.13.0-24-generic. How can I download and install wifi driver for above mentioned Network adapter Realtek RTL8723BE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the drivers from [GitHub](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new).

Get a temporary internet connection, then open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtl8723be
```

Your wifi should now be working.

Comment: I followed your answer and install this driver. But the problem with me is when sit near to the wifi router i get connected but when i get into other room my wifi get disconnected and my system doesn't show any available wifi. I have another laptop with ubuntu in the same room and it works perfect but that one has intel wireless. Is there any way i can get wifi signals with realtek ? Earlier on this laptop was installed windows 10 and it was working fine so it is not a hardware problem.