# Facing issues with Realtek RTL8723BE wireless adapter

Tags: networking, realtek, ubuntu-drivers

I am facing issue with realtek RTL8723BE wireless adapter. Very poor reception and for a very short range.

I tried installing the new driver from the github 
[How to install Realtek RTL8723BE wifi PCIe Wireless Network Adapter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/623001/how-to-install-realtek-rtl8723be-wifi-pcie-wireless-network-adapter)

But there is no difference after that also.

Kindly help.

Regards,
Ankit Jain

Comment: refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/517772/lenovo-e540-rtl8723be-wifi-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with Realtek wireless card's bug in itself. Most users with Realtek RTL8723BE are facing issues with the Wi-Fi connection. Tweaks are required to solve the issue. Check the link shared below with similar issues, a possible working solution via command is given there. Try it, maybe it will work for you as well.

*https://askubuntu.com/questions/727512/a-posibble-solution-for-lenovo-users-with-realtek-wireless-card-to-solve-their-w*

Good luck!