# Ubuntu 14.04 Realtek RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless issues

Tags: networking, drivers, realtek

I'm a novice to ubuntu. I'm looking for help to make configure this wireless? It shows very feeble network-strength despite being juxtaposition to the router and won't connect to internet for longer than few seconds. 
Ive tried followings from various pages at askubuntu.com:

[Attempt 1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632719/my-wifi-drops-the-connection-after-a-few-minutes-realtek8723be/673826#673826) :

```
$ echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

Attempt 2: (mentioned at same above link):

```
sudo rmmod rtl8723be && sudo modprobe rtl8723be
```

[Attempt 3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/623001/how-to-install-realtek-rtl8723be-wifi-pcie-wireless-network-adapter):

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtl8723be
```

[Attempt 4](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370108):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Did a reboot after every attempt but nothing seems to work. Can someone please point me to a thread where it may have been resolved successfully, or provide a solution?

Thanks for every help.

Comment: Thanks Neil. Would you know the solution?

Comment: Hi Tobis, I tried your response http://askubuntu.com/a/623026/470757 on same issue on my laptop. It hasn't worked for me. Any idea? Thanks  http://askubuntu.com/users/349821/tobias-lekare