# iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|quality'

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, scanner

Like many people with a Realtek RTL8723BE Wi-Fi controller I have issues catching Networks. I followed the answer from here:

https://askubuntu.com/a/1079892/898693

But at point 7,when entering:

`iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|quality'`

I get following output:

```
enp3s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

```

So my question is, if there's another way arround to test which antena I should use?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you successfully installed Wi-Fi driver? `enp3s0` is generally logical name of the Ethernet Interface. You can check logical names of network adapters using `sudo lshw -C network | grep 'network\|description\|logical name'` and indeed Ethernet interface doesn't support scanning. What is the output of `rfkill list all`?  Alternatively you can also use `nmcli dev wifi`.

Comment: So, I moved closer to the router and I got following output:

[enp3s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

                    Quality=38/70  Signal level=-72 dBm  
                    ESSID:"BO_Oficina"]

Comment: I moved closer to the router andgot following output:

[enp3s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

                    Quality=38/70  Signal level=-72 dBm  
                    ESSID:"BO_Oficina"]

The difference between the two antennas in minimal, -72dBm and -78dBn. Using the network scanner of my MacBook position next to the HP labtop gives me -42dBm.
Is there way to improve reception of the HP or should I just buy a USB Wirless adapter?
Sorry about not be able to properly format the output. Tried with ```vbut its not working.

Comment: changing value of ant_sel generally works. I generally refer [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/623001/) while installing driver for the same. You can also refer linked duplicates.

Comment: changing the value of ```ant_sel``` worked, but the difference is very weak. ant-sel=1 was -72dBm and ant_sel=2 -78dBm. Would I get better wifi reception with an USB adapter?

Comment: Have you tried downgrading kernel version?

Comment: Sorry, total noob here... what does that mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86489/discussion-between-kulfy-and-quilmes).